# Split returning specific number of elements

Tags: powershell, split

I know this is relative simple task, but I am new to PowerShell and internet search is not really helping me in this case :(

I have the following strings -

```
server1.us.domain.com
server2.domain.com
```

and I would like to extract the dns suffix from these, ie.

```
us.domain.com
domain.com
```

I tried several methods. The closest I could go so far is

```
$a = 'us.domain.com'

PS C:\> $a.Split('.')
us
domain
com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. You should use the 2nd parameter of that Split method. Which specifies the number of elements to return. `$a` in this case is "server1.us.domain.com"

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $a.Split('.',2)
server1
us.domain.com
```

You could call the second element of the returned array to just get the domain name.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $a.Split('.',2)[1]
us.domain.com
```

## Some alternate solutions

For completeness another way to do it would be to join the elements after the fact. Other simple things you could do as well. In this particular case there are unnecessary but they are solutions nonetheless.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> ($a.Split(".") | Select -Skip 1) -join "."
us.domain.com
```

Could also use `.Substring()`. This relies on `.IndexOf()` to find the index of the first period.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $a.Substring($a.IndexOf(".") + 1)
us.domain.com
```

A tiny regex solution as well. Replace before the first period with nothing.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $a -replace "^.+?\."
us.domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I knew it was going to be simple :)  I will mark this as an answer once SO allows me to do so.

Comment: Nice and complete answer Matt.